# I need to center image into div with css

Tags: html, css

I need to center image inside my div but when i use some code it will change my other code and that is like magic circle.

My HTML http://textuploader.com/d40ta
My CSS http://textuploader.com/d40t5

Comment: use the snippet and add your code into your question .. avoid using external links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CSS3 Solution:**

Simply modify the below CSS class.

```
.iui {
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    top: 20px;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    background-color: red;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

**CSS Solution:**

In the below solution, we need to set the CSS property `line-height` the same as that of the element height for the class `iui`. Then we need to set the image inside the div with the CSS properties `display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle`, this will center the image.

```
.iui {
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    line-height: 200px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: red;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

.iui img{
  vertical-align:middle;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Images are inline-block by default. That means you can center them inside a block-level parent by using `text-align: center`. `<div>` or `<p>` elements, to name a few, are block-level by default, but you can make almost any element block-level by applying `display: block` to that element.

If the image is `display: block` already, you can center it by applying `margin: 0 auto` where the `auto` is the functional value (the first value could be any unit, adding margin to the top and bottom of the image).